# Как передать переменную в sql код?

Tags: c#, sql

Я задаю название базы даных, которую я хочу создать, через командную строку и сохраняю как переменную :

```
      String inputDatabase = GetDatabaseName(args);
```

C документа query.sql я читаю следующий запрос:

```
  "ALTER DATABASE [{0}] SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON;ALTER DATABASE [{0}] SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON;";
```

Как мне «связать» переменную inputDatabase с {0}  в запросе?

Возможно мой вопрос не коректен, буду благодарна за замечания.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String inputDatabase = GetDatabaseName(args);
String sqlTemplate = "ALTER DATABASE [{0}] SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON;ALTER DATABASE [{0}] SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON;";
String sql = string.Format(sqlTemplate, inputDatabase);
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает :)